# wordpress subpage tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme right now and I'm using conditionals in the sidebar to display different information for each page like so:

```
if (is_page('services')) {
 etc.....
} elseif (etc....
```

However, some of the subpages do not have their own specific conditional. How can I make it so that a conditional for a parent page applies to its subpages as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a number of ways. There might be an easier way, but this is what I would do:
On the page itself, check if it is a child page:

```
     if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) 
     {
          // This is a subpage
          return true;

     } 
     else 
     {
         // This is not a subpage
         return false;
     }
```

which will check if the page is a child, in which case you can fetch the conditional from the parent the same way you are currently, except specify the parent instead of the current page when checking.

Comment: This seems sort of a roundabout way to do this. (However, I don't claim to be any sort of expert in php. :D ) Shouldn't there be a way to specify in the conditional itself to include the subpages?

Comment: Or maybe there's a tag that looks like this: if(is_page_and_subpages('services')) {

Comment: I see what you want to do, but it's not that easy. It's not how PHP works as much as it is how Wordpress works. You could do this a number of other ways, but it's easier to do this than it is to pass a variable from parent to child. If I go directly to your child page, I never accessed your parent page, so the variable has to be set in a function or on the child page regardless. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can also put this snippet of code in your functions.php file and use it anywhere on your wp code.

```
    function is_subpage() {
    global $post;                                 // load details about this page
        if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {      // test to see if the page has a parent
               $parentID = $post->post_parent;        // the ID of the parent is this
               return $parentID;                      // return the ID
        } else {                                      // there is no parent so...
               return false;                          // ...the answer to the question is false
        };
};
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags